# assistance when installing pytorch using pip

Tags: python, pip, pytorch

I am trying to install pytorch on windows 10, python 3.10 with the pip from the website:

```
pip3 install torch torchvision torchaudio
```

and I get the following error:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for torch
```

Comment: Pytorch only supports Python 3.6 through 3.9.

Comment: Thanks very much!